# C# - Create a hash of a string to an integer between a particular range

Tags: c#, hash, colors

I am trying to implement a form of random colour generator.

What i am planning on doing, is to create a hash of a string (Employee's name) to generate a hexadecimal value (#0 to #FFFFFF), therefore causing that employee to always correspond to the same colour.

Does anybody have an approach to do this that may work?

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**

```
            MD5 hasher = MD5.Create();
            var hashed = hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(r.Employee.Name));
            var intColor = BitConverter.ToInt32(hashed, 0);
            color = intColor.ToString("X");
```

This is what i have so far, however there seems to be an issue with it somewhere as it displays the standard blue colour for everything

Comment: Please share what have you tried?

Comment: I hope the resulting color will be distinguishable from the background. ;)

Comment: @RichaGarg please see edit.

Comment: @SarveshMishra if you have a way to avoid this also would be great (white background)

Comment: @DaRoGa When you manipulate the final integer value of color, `int finalColorVal = (int) colorVal * 9211020 / 16777215`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `#0` to `#FFFFFF` range is **3 bytes**, we can compute the hash as usual and then take, say, first 3 bytes:

```
public static String md5_hash3(String value) {
  using (var hash = MD5.Create()) {
    return String.Concat(hash
      .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value))
      .Take(3)
      .Select(item => item.ToString("X2")));
  }
}
```

...

```
 String result = md5_hash3(r.Employee.Name);
```

Comment: Where would the distinguishing string (employee name) come into this?

Comment: @DaRoGa it is a parameter for the method

Comment: @Richa Garg: *any* hash is *never* unique: since strings can be up to 2 GB and the hash is at most 256 bit (SHA-256), collisions (two or more different strings that have the same hash value) are inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it this way:

```
int maxValue = int.Parse("FFFFFF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
var intColor = BitConverter.ToInt32(hashed, 0);
intColor = intColor % maxValue;
var color = intColor.ToString("X");
```

Also it will not definitely guarantee you nice colors.

Comment: What is your intention with `var intColor = ...;`

Comment: I am not bothered about 'nice' colours, just as long as the colours for each employee is always the same

Comment: `intColor` is your computed hash